# Disabling RAID1 on a 2x1TB NVME Ubuntu Linux setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid

I'm sorry if this is worded weirdly as I'm quite new to dealing with RAID, apologies for that (any edits would be appreciated if this is worded wrong).

That out of the way, on my remote dedicated server, I've got 2 x 1 TB NVME drives in a RAID1 setup, and I want to break this RAID so data is only on one drive. We're running Ubuntu 22.04.
I need access to the other drive as I need to re-partition it to create separate volumes as we're using software that requires a separate partition for KVM VPS' (basically we need a separate parition for us to run VPSs).

I've tried putting GParted on a USB and tried re-partitioning the drives but because of the RAID setup, nothing can be done in GParted.

Comment: It depends on how the RAID was made. So, did you used `mdadm`, other, or is it a hardware RAID?

Comment: Hardware or software RAID? Are you aware this is a high risk operation? Also, this sounds very much like an XY question.

Comment: The RAID was setup when we bought the dedicated server off a provider -- is there a way to check this?

Comment: If the host allows you to do this, great. They'll be able to tell you how to do it. If the host doesn't present this functionality to you, you're out of luck. Either way, it seems you need to ask your host.

Comment: @music2myear I've tried and they've literally said resetting the machine would be the easiest way. I've tried requesting other approaches but they've simply dodged the question, which isn't helpful, but the hosting itself is great and the support isn't too bad (they start charging money if its jobs like this). That's why I made a post here to see if there's a way; I can boot from an ISO, that's an option if it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure this out by intentionally failing one of the drives (via a command) on the RAID1 setup (which to my understanding backs up content from one drive to another -- so effectively it should be safe (I'm not an expert on this, so don't bet on it, any corrections please do let me know)).

### Guide

Thanks to a [guide by Benjamin Cane](https://bencane.com/2011/07/06/mdadm-manually-fail-a-drive/), I was able to intentionally disable (by failing the drive on) my second drive on my RAID1 setup. As we had 2x1TB Samsung SSD drives I wanted to disable one of them, so we could effectively make use of all the drives.

I'm confident enough to use the CLI as we're using Ubuntu Server, but not confident enough to manage drives safely. So I temporarily installed `cockpit` and used the `storage` aspect of it to examine the volumes on the drive, to refamiliarize myself with what the names of the volumes and drives were. I was also able to use Cockpit to keep on examining the structure of the drives which was quite helpful.

[image]

Am able to see the main filesystem source from how large it is and its mount location.

[image]

This was especially helpful in showing what disks were part of this filesystem ('disks' on the right). Underneath it also shows the drive name, which comes useful later on when using `mdadm`.

I was able to do this by using `mdadm`:

- Viewing the setup of the drive `mdadm --detail [volume e.g. /dev/md10]`
  From this, I'm able to see what drives are part of the RAID1 setup so then disabling the drives from there is easy.
- Failing the drive `mdadm [volume e.g. /dev/md10] -f [drive want to fail e.g. /dev/sdc1]`
  Then using the `mdadm --detail` command again to check that the drive has been removed.
- Removing the drive from the RAID1 setup `mdadm [volume e.g. /dev/md10] -r [drive that's been failed e.g. /dev/sdc1]`
  Then using the `mdadm --detail` command once more to confirm that everything has gone through correctly.

I haven't yet rebooted the machine and I'm not especially sure if something else is meant to be done to disable the RAID1 fully. If anyone knows any additional info, please let me know!